# Does Fluent-Hibernate exist?

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Is there something like Fluent-NHibernate for the original Java Hibernate? If not, why not? Are there any language-specific limitations?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe Fluent-NHibernate relies on the nice features provided by Linq in C#3.0 if I'm not mistaken. Until Java implements lambda expressions etc I don't think we'll see Fluent Hibernate.

I could be wrong though. :)

Comment: good point. I was concentrating on the fluent style interface and was wondering if this is a problem and couldn't found any. But inside the concatenated calls there are lambda expressions, doh!

Comment: From the horses mouth (I'm the lead developer on Fluent NHibernate): the reason Fluent Hibernate doesn't exist is exactly because of the lack of lambda expressions. It's not just the lack of basic lambdas, but the ability to parse those expressions that FNH relies heavily on; without which you'd need to resort to strings and that's no better than XML in my opinion. It's always a possibility for the future though.

Comment: @James: While using lambdas as data is cool, I find the convention based mapping is my primary motivation for using FNH. It's insanely easy to "get something working", and then lock down the schema later. The only problem I see is the fact that the nested closure pattern is used throughout FNH; while that works well with C#, Java doesn't have support for anonymous methods (although you can create functors via anonymous classes). I think Fluent Hibernate would work quite well in Scala, and it could kinda sorta work in Java.

Comment: A year after making my comment, my thoughts pretty much mirror yours. If you feel like discussing this further, drop a message on the [FNH mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/fluent-nhibernate).

Comment: @James - how could this be done in Scala. AFAIK it's more than just the lambdas that are required its a means of parsing the expressions and looking at an object representation of the AST. In scala you can create a lambda, but only execute it, and not examine it. I'd guess that FNH looks at something like foo => foo.bar and can see that the expression represents access to the property named "bar" which it uses in its mappings. Is this not possible in scala/groovy?

Comment: @Owen - I'm not familiar enough with Scala or Groovy to really say whether you could reproduce the "static reflection" part of FNH; you're correct in your assumptions though, FNH uses .Net's `Expression` tree objects, which allow you to inspect to structure of an anonymous method without executing it. I wrote a bit of a summary on this subject a couple of years ago: [Introduction to Static Reflection](http://jagregory.com/writings/introduction-to-static-reflection/)

Comment: What's the answer in late 2018?

Answer (score 2):

Groovy supports lambda expressions (although they rather confusingly call them closures), and Groovy classes are directly accessible from Java. Perhaps the mappings for Java apps could be written in Groovy.

Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

Scala supports lambda's, right (I'm totally Scala newbie). And it is completely inter-operable with Java at the static compilation level. It seems like Scala+Hibernate would enable fluent on the Java side.

Comment: To be completely pedantic, it would enable "fluent" on the JVM side.